# Angular2 routing according to data received from callback

Tags: angular2-routing

Im getting confused what content app.routes.ts  should contain according to my logic.
so here's the logic:
I have the following components: Login, User, Admin
my app component includes the login component.
within my login component i have that view that is render:

```
<div class="login" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html" *ngIf="!isLogged">
<label for="username">Username: </label>
<input type="text" id="username" [(ngModel)]="username"/>
<label for="password">password: </label>
<input type="password" id="password" [(ngModel)]="password"/>
<button id="login" (click)="login()"">Login</button>
</div>
<div *ngIf="isLogged" class="container">
<router-outlet name="user" *ngIf="access == 'user'"></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="admin" *ngIf="access == 'admin'"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

As you can see I want to render user component or admin component according to the data returned from the login function.

the login function is the following:

```
login() {
this._httpservice.postService('http://localhost:3000/authenticate', {username: this.username , password: this.password }).then(res => {
    this.access = res.role;
    if(this.access === 'user' || this.access === 'admin'){
        this.isLogged = true;
    }
});
```

}

i dont know how to build the routes file or maybe i am missing the concept of it.
so feel free to modify my code.

edit: 
app.module.ts

`

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { UserComponent } from './user/user.component';
import { AdminComponent } from './admin/admin.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { HttpService } from './http.service';
import { routes } from './app.router';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    UserComponent,
    AdminComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    routes
  ],
  providers: [HttpService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="login" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html" *ngIf="!isLogged">
<label for="username">Username: </label>
<input type="text" id="username" [(ngModel)]="username"/>
<label for="password">password: </label>
<input type="password" id="password" [(ngModel)]="password"/>
<button id="login" (click)="login()"">Login</button>
</div>
```

Im guessing this is from your LoginComponent

```
login() {
    this._httpservice.postService('http://localhost:3000/authenticate', {username: this.username , password: this.password }).then(res => {
            this.access = res.role;
            if(this.access === 'user' ){
                this.isLogged = true;
                this.router.navigate(['user']); 
            }
            if(this.access === 'admin'){
                 this.isLogged = true;
                 this.router.navigate(['admin']);
            }
        });
    }
```

and you must connect user and admin route to their components!
app.module.ts:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
 { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
 { path: 'user', component: UserComponent},
 { path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent}
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
      { enableTracing: true } // <-- debugging purposes only
    )
    // other imports here
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

You need a `router-outlet` in your app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';
}
```

Comment: When i put the user credentials i fet the following error in console:
Error cannot find primary outlet to load usercomponent.
Maybe i have to to add another route object into my routes file?

Comment: Router Event: NavigationError
browser_adapter.js:122 NavigationError(id: 3, url: '/user', error: Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'user')

Comment: NavigationError(id: 2, url: '/login/user', error: Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'UserComponent')

Comment: you should really read the angular documentation. im running this right now! gl

Comment: be careful. admin and user routes are not protected. use something like jason web token for authentication [read this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken)

Comment: Ye i know in that assignment they dont care about security so its ok.